# I'm learning Typescript. How can you explain this?

Tags: typescript

[image]

`[1,2]` is the output. Not `False`. It should  be `[1,2]` and `False`.

How can the compiler ignore Console.log statement and print `[1,2]` instead?

I know the code is just 3 lines, but if you think there is an explanation involved in it to better understand and write good code.

Comment: Posting the code here is the better way than sharing image .. refer this link before post a query .. it helps   [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't ignoring the `console.log` call. Your code is printing the value that is returned by `outpt(false)` which is what you have in the return statement.

Your code isn't using the supplied argument at all. If you want it to print false, then use `all` in the return statement, not `[1,2]`. All you're returning is a hardcoded array.

If you want it to return  `[1,2] false`, try something like `return [1,2] + ' ' + all;`